# General date format in an application to use in HTML file labels

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am updating an application in Angular.

I want to set the format of the date as a general value for the application.

In other words, I want to have the format as a string, stored as a constant somewhere, or as a global string/setting.

As of now, I have:

```html
<p>{{creationDate | date: 'd/M/y, hh:mm'}}</p>
```

All I really need, is to have `'d/M/y, hh:mm'` as a stored value somewhere, which I can then use in any HTML file. For that matter, getting it from a global place in the ts file is fine by me.

How do I set the format as a variable or constant?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using AngularJS, you can put the date format in a variable in scope, or use a module `.constant()` and inject it:

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .constant("dateFmt", "d/M/y, hh:mm")
  .controller("dateFmtCtrl", function($scope, dateFmt) {
    $scope.creationDate = new Date();
    $scope.dateFmt = dateFmt;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="dateFmtCtrl">
  <p>{{creationDate | date: dateFmt}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create a Shared Service: date-format.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root',
        })
        export class DateFormatService {
          dateFormat: string = 'd/M/y, hh:mm';
        }
```

**Inject the Service in a Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { DateFormatService } from './date-format.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-my-component',
      template: '<p>{{creationDate | date: dateFormat}}</p>',
    })
    export class MyComponent {
       creationDate: Date;
  dateFormat: string;

  constructor(private dateFormatService: DateFormatService) {
    this.creationDate = new Date();
    this.dateFormat = this.dateFormatService.dateFormat; // Access the dateFormat property from the service
   
  }
    }
```